# Some application alias names result in Error401.2: Unauthorised message on IIS

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, model-view-controller

I am experiencing a weird issue with application alias naming conventions in IIS

I have an asp.net application deployed to a folder on my server "c:\sites\Demo52"

In IIS under Default Web Site I add an application setting the alias to "Demo" and the physical path to point to my application at "c:\sites\Demo52".
The application pool is set to DefaultAppPool  (.NET V4 Integrated)

When I then browse the application I receive "Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration."

Now, if I remove the application and start again, this time using an alias of "Aemo", when I browse the application it works perfectly.

On further investigation it appears that some alias names do not work...
Demo, Pemo, Remo

and some do for example.
Aemo, Bemo, Cemo, Eemo, Femo, Gemo, etc. to the end of the alphabet.

In fact, it appears that Alias' starting with the letter D, P or R all fail.
So, while "DickDastadly" fails miserably,  "CaptainCaveman" is just fine.

Further to this, in our application's Web.config we have

```
<authentication mode="None">
```

since we perform our own authentication.

Setting

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

resolves the 401 error for all alias names, however, we are then not necessarily performing our own authentication as we'd like and I can see nothing in our code that would even care about a sites alias.

So, I'm wondering if anyone has experienced anything similar or has any views on how to mitigate this issue.

Comment: could you share your own authentication code? which level did you apply your authentication? which module you are using native or managed?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I cannot share the authorisation code however, I'm convinced the issue does not lay with that code.  I've noted that in the web.config there are a number of location tags handling access to various resources across the deployed application.  The paths for some of these location tags correspond to the first letter of the alias names that are failing.  I need to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

I traced the issue to some `<location path="x"><authorization><allow verbs="get" users="?" /></authorization></system.web></location>` elements in the our application's web.config (where x = either d, p or r) and allowing 
our app bundles and minifies various artefacts to urls that have either "d", "p", or "r" in their paths.

While I don't fully understand the reasons, it seems that when a site is aliased with a name starting d, p or r the issue occurs.

The solution for our application was simply to use a much less likely naming convention so for example the path to "p" is now "xpkg".